# Passing variables in OPENQUERY

Tags: concatenation, sql-server-2014, openquery

I have no doubt I'm missing something minute, but nonetheless, I'm not sure what it is. Here's the query:

```
DECLARE @START DATE, @END DATE, @MySQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @START = '12/1/2020'
SELECT @END = '12/10/2020'

SET @MySQL =
'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([SERVERNAME], ''SELECT * FROM TABLE (NOLOCK) WHERE InitiatedDate BETWEEN ' + @Start + ' AND ' + @End + ')'
EXEC (@MySQL)
```

I get this error:

> The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator

I tested this concatenation method with a similar query and it worked, no problem:

```
SET @MySQL =
'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([SERVER], ''SELECT top ' + @X + '  * FROM TABLE'')'
EXEC (@MySQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is probably working because @X was a VARCHAR data type.

In your main example, @START and @END are defined as DATE data types, so logically you cannot append them to a VARCHAR data type in the same way that adding 6 and 'six' doesn't result in either of 12 or '6six'.

You need to make use of the CONVERT function to change your DATE back to the string representation of a DATE. Be careful to use the format option to get the string in a format that can then be automatically converted back to a DATE when the query runs.

`'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([SERVERNAME], ''SELECT * FROM TABLE (NOLOCK) WHERE InitiatedDate BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @Start, 101) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @End, 101) + ''')'`